# Creating a boost::asio::ip::udp::socket crashing in LIB after updating from 1_55 to 1_62 on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-asio

This is driving me nuts. Mainly because it happens 90% of the time, but occasionally I can get right by it.

So here's the backstory. I had compiled boost 1_55 using MSVC++ 2012, and we had been using it for quite a while. We are switching over to the 2013 toolchain finally and I've been tasked with upgrading everything.

I chose to grab the latest boost 1_62, and recompile with the 2013 32-bit toolset. The problem I'm having is that now that I've recompiled I am getting a crash on creating a udp socket.

So I have a library that we developed that we link statically. I inherit from that library and call a method that opens a UDP Port.

For the sake of the example I have changed my code to best illistrate this point:

In the class constructor I have the following:

```
        boost::asio::io_service test;
        boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(test);

        this->StartListen();
```

That works just fine. In StartListen, I call Init I have the following:

```
        boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint listen_endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(m_bindAddress), m_usPort);
    m_mcast_endpoint.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(m_sendAddress), m_usPort));
    m_socket.reset(new boost::asio::ip::udp::socket(m_ioservice));
```

This blows up on the m_socket.reset with this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x77D798C1 (ntdll.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77DAC8D0).
```

Interestly enough when I changed the example to be the immediately in the start listen like this:

```
  void Multicast::StartListen()
{
    boost::asio::io_service take2;
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket_test(take2);
```

I get this:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6384D4A1 in program.exe: 0xC00001A5: An invalid exception handler routine has been detected (parameters: 0x00000003).
```

I really have no idea what's going on here. I built boost with the

b2.exe --build-type=complete --stagedir=bin32 address-model=32 stage

and everything seems correct. What am I missing?

Well I've made more progress. The issue happens when you create a boost UDP socket in a library, and create a boost UDP socket in the code calling the library.

```
So: 
Main 
| 
| Create UDP Socket 
| 
CALL LIBRARY 
 | 
 | 
 | Create UDP SOCKET <--- Heap corruption
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Boost.ASIO and using it from two separate projects. Putting the BOOST_ASIO_DISABLE_IOCP define in both project properties fixed the problem. There is probably a "better way" of using IOCP, but this solved it going forward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you compile with headers of 1_55 but link with libs of 1_62

Comment: Thought of that, I renamed the directory the 1_55 headers were in. Which I thought fixed it, as it worked after a recompile. 

Once, then hit the error the next time through. It's a real head scratcher.

Comment: Nope, I blew away the old 1_55 headers and libraries, still have the same result.

I put together a small test application trying to recreate it, and it doesn't exhibit the same behavior. I'm going to have to slowly cut parts of my application away until I figure out what it is I guess.

Comment: I have no other ideas about this problem, tell me why if you solve the problem, ^_^

Comment: Interesting if I move the class to a header only mode it's happy. But I haven't figured out why yet.

Comment: Well I've made more progress.

The issue happens when you create a boost UDP socket in a library, and create a boost UDP socket in the code calling the library.

So:

Main
  |
  |  Create UDP Socket
  |
CALL LIBRARY
         |
         |
         |
        Create UDP SOCKET               <--- Heap corruption.